# Error in FreeControls.PersianDateTimePicker.Finalize()

Tags: c#

I using PersianDate.dll in my Project and when want to exit from program one exeption is happened .

FreeControls.PersianDateTimePicker.Finalize()

Comment: What is the description of exception?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>WaterSystemManagement.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception>

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PersianDate.dll
at FreeControls.PersianDateTimePicker.Finalize()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I case anyone else having same problem as : FreeControls.PersianDateTimePicker.Finalize() error
with PersianDate (http://persiancontrol.codeplex.com/)

there is the solution that worked for me:

Just Dispose the Control that you used in your form or project

```
    private FreeControls.PersianDateTimePicker dt1;
    private FreeControls.PersianDateTimePicker dt2;
```

.
.
.

```
    private void yourForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //because of a bug in dateTime dll, they need to be Disposed
        dt1.Dispose();
        dt2.Dispose();
    }
```